# How to run tests with Dart 2.0 preview

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using the Dart SDK in the latest install of Flutter:

```
Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.43.0.flutter-52afcba357 (Fri Mar 30 20:33:12 2018 +0000) on "windows_x64"
```

I can run individual tests with Dart 2.0 (now in preview) by using the `--preview-dart-2` command-line argument, e.g:

```
$ dart --preview-dart-2 test\my_test.dart
```

But is it possible to run **all tests** with Dart 2.0, e.g:

```
$ pub run test
```

This only runs the test suite as Dart 1.x which doesn't seem to accept the `--preview-dart-2` flag.

Comment: How is that related to Flutter? Flutter tests are run with `flutter test`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm using the Dart SDK contained in the Flutter install to run Dart tests.

Comment: Then you are just running plain Dart tests from inside a Flutter project. This doesn't make the question related to Flutter.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It indicates I'm using the latest version of Dart SDK contained in the Flutter Install.

Comment: Can't make any sense of your latest comment. A Flutter directory doesn't prevent you from adding Dart tests. If you run the tests with `pub run` or `dart ...` then they are not Flutter tests and not related to Flutter.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It's really simple, I've installed flutter, I've created tests using its Dart SDK. The `pub run tests` does not run in Dart 2.0 Strong mode where as Flutter and running dart with `--preview-dart-2` does. I understand that you don't think it's not related to Flutter, but given I've installed Flutter and like I've said in my previous 2 comments, I believe it does. Please don't keep repeating your same point, it adds no value and wastes comment space in-place of future comments that could be adding more valuable context related to the actual question.

Comment: I think it adds value. Either what you are doing doesn't make sense, or your question is stated wrongly. I just tried to get to the point where the misunderstanding is. If you're not interested then I won't bother you any more.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Keep this up and I'm going to rescind your incomplete answer. Exactly which part of the question is **stated wrongly**?

Comment: Flutter tests are run with `flutter test` https://flutter.io/testing/#unit-testing. What you seem to have are Dart tests stored inside a Flutter project. That doesn't make them related to Flutter. I don't care if you do that, but I think it makes your question quite confusing.

Comment: I've not mentioned Flutter anywhere in my question so it's pretty hard for it to be **stated wrongly** as you've strongly claimed. But I'll add a note to say that I'm using Dart SDK from Flutter so it actually does mention it.

Comment: You added the `flutter` tag.

Comment: Yes I'm very aware of that thank you, you've been most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pub run` doesn't support `--preview-dart-2` yet and I'm sure `pub test` depends on `pub run`.

There is an open issue [Implement `--preview-dart-2` option for `pub run` #1807](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1807)